# Redirect single user agent to a specific RSS feed

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, rss, block, flipboard

I have asked this before and since then done a lot of searching but I can't find a solution other than a suspicion that it will be a targeted 301 redirect in htaccess - having read https://support.google.com/feedburner/answer/78464?hl=en

If anyone can assist I would be really grateful. I have a heap of feeds - many I'm not aware of I imagine (Wordpress). I have created a specific feed for a single purpose (Flipboard). I'm not sure what the Flipboard user agent is, but if I can establish that, is there a way to block it from accessing all RSS feeds except the feed I have created specifically for it?

I am at your mercy :-) Skip.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a rules like this in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

# if USER_AGENT is flipboard (or whatever)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} flipboard
# if accessing any feed other than /path/to/flipboard-feed.xml
# then give Forbidden error
RewriteRule !^path/to/flipboard-feed\.xml$ - [F]
```